# How to change start menu appearance and sysprep after removing Xbox App

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I am creating a Windows 10 Pro 32 & 64bit image.

I would like to remove the Xbox App which I know can be done via an escalated PS:

`Get-AppxPackage *xboxapp* | Remove-AppxPackage`

But will this cause any issues in sysprep as all provisioned apps will have updated.

Also, I am looking to have the start menu a normal size, as Windows 7 and other versions.  See the image bellow for an example.

I know how to do this for a logged in user, but this image will be being used on domain machines so obviously I need to do this for all users that may login.

Thanks

[image: This for all users not the expanded version with live tiles.]

This for all users not the expanded version with live tiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by running (In an elevated PowerShell):

`Export-StartLayout -Path "C:\LOCATION\FILENAME.XML"`

Then open GPEDIT.MSC > Computer Config > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar > Start Layout.  Edit this one, and add the path to the above XML file, reboot and it should work.

Running the above PS to remove an app caused no errors in SysPrep